Weak convergence of measure and their total variation measures.
Does weak convergence of Radon measures implies weak convergence of their total variation measures?  Precisely speaking, I want to know whether the following proposition is correct.

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $\mu_k$ is a sequence of signed(or vector valued) Radon measures such that $\mu_k$ converges weakly to $\mu_0$. Namely, for any $\phi \in C_c(X)$,
\begin{equation}
\int_{X}\phi d\mu_k \to \int_{X} \phi d\mu_0.
\end{equation}
Then $|\mu_k|$ converges weakly to $|\mu_0|$.


$\mu_k=\delta_k, \mu_0=0$.

@geetha290krm  I mean  total variation measure, not total variation. Updated.

I'm guessing this should be doable using the polar decomposition $d\mu = h d|\mu|$ with $\forall x,, |h(x)| = 1$, in some fashion?

(Decided to turn my answer into a comment) There appear to exist counterexamples to the fact that the hypothesis would imply the convergence of $(\mu_k^+)_k$ to $\mu_0^+$, see the answer by gerw to this post here If $\mu_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}\mu$, then $\mu^+_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu^+$ and $\mu^-_n \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}\mu^-$, and we have $\mu_k^+ = \frac{1}{2}(|\mu_k| + \mu_k)$ so it would also be a counterexample to your claim.
It also seems however that upon placing an additional condition you do have conver

@geetha290krm and OP, it's been a while, but I've decided to turn my previous answer into a comment due to its current lack of verifiability.
